# What's the result of a secondary color mixed with the third primary color?

Tags: color, color-theory

I am currently developing a puzzle game which requires the player to blend colors in order to solve the puzzles. I am using the RYB model because I think it's the most logical when it comes to blending colors : green is blue + yellow. I'm cheating a bit to avoid very dark colors, my colors are bright as if I was working with light.

I am introducing secondary and tertiary colors to make the puzzles more challenging. However, I am having a bit of trouble handling 1 case : what happens when someone mixes orange with blue? Or purple + yellow? Or green + red? Do they result in the same color? What is the hue of this color based on the hue of the primary colors that were used? I have no paint to try this out, and I'm not sure how to simulate those mix on Photoshop

Comment: Shouldn't your algorithm already calculate this result for you?

Comment: No algorithm involved here, since the player can only use primary colors and cannot paint over a ternary color, the number of possibilities is so little that I hardcoded the resulting colors so I can have the shades I want

Comment: I would strongly recommend... DO NOT USE the RYB model. It is an archaic model.

Comment: Might be, though IMHO, I don't think many people would think that green+red=yellow when playing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The precise colours achieved would depend on the particular shade of colours mixed.

However, generally speaking, in subtractive colour systems (such as CMYK or RYB): orange + blue, yellow + purple, and red + green, all make various shades of brown or greyish brown.  In fact, if you mix any red, yellow, or blue primary colour with a non-primary colour (with the exception perhaps of red and orange), then you will probably get some shade of brown - or as I like to refer to it "mud".

[image]

If you want to experiment with real paint, then get some red, yellow, and blue paint, and try mixing them up yourself.

The example below might be a bit more accurate than the one above. Here I used MyPaint which simulates paint and blending of paint colours.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The resulting colors from the mixing of the complementary colors, or the opposites in the chromatic circle, and the corresponding ones towards black and white; in Spanish are called **colores quebrados** or **colores rotos** (broken colors, sorry  I didn't find any equivalence in English). I'll use the name of broken colors for this answer, maybe someone helps with the real english name.

### Chromatic circle

[image: Chromatic circle]

### Broken colors of complementary red and cyan

[image: red and cyan]

### Broken colors of complementary orange and lightblue

[image: orange and lightblue]

### Broken colors of complementary yellow and blue

[image: yellow/blue]

### Broken colors of complementary light-green and violet

[image: Lgreen/violet]

### Broken colors of complementary green and magenta

[image: green/magenta]

### Broken colors of complementary blue-green and rose

[image: greenblue and rose]

Comment: Hello Danielillo, is there a script you used to create these colour maps?

Comment: No, it's Illustrator blending.