# How to add new colors but keep the same color scheme/temperature?

Tags: color

Sorry, I'm not sure if those are the right terms. So, here is an example.

Let's say I want to add blue to this design:

[image]

[Source](https://www.freepik.com/free-vector/japanese-food-with-flat-elements_846711.htm#term=japanese%20food&page=4&position=16).

How do I pick a blue that matches the existing mood/temperature?

Answer (score 18):

Being a composition that mostly uses warm colors, using the *broken color schemes* of [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/114049/120647), after locating each color or the approximate one, you can easily find the complementary that would correspond to the cold color or blue keeping the same value.

[image]

[image]